# How to use wETH in a smart contract deployed in BSC?

Tags: solidity, binance, binance-smart-chain

I'm new in the blockchain development and I have a question.
Right now I'm developing a smart contract in the Binance Smart Chain and I need to transfer wETH and receive wETH, but I don't know how to use this token.

I cannot find a token contract address of wETH.

Answer (score 1):

I think Binance Smart Chain does not use term wETH but just ETH or "ETH BEP-20". Accordingly to https://bscscan.com/tokens the right token should be https://bscscan.com/token/0x2170ed0880ac9a755fd29b2688956bd959f933f8

Answer (score 1):

In Binance Smart Chain there is no wETH by definition. There is wBNB instead, which is the analogy for wETH in Ethereum.
You may refer to it as a stanard bep-20 token, and the address is https://bscscan.com/token/0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c